# Как указать правильный путь к файлу

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Как правильно указать путь в App.js (реакт) к файлу, который находится по пути `D:\Test\frontend\chat-app\src\components\Chat\jsx\ChatLogic.jsx`,
если в терминале я нахожусь в директории `D:\Test\frontend`?

Answer (score 1):

```
import ChatLogic from './chat-app/src/components/Chat/jsx/ChatLogic.jsx';
```